# using kinect skeleton - no interest in wpf drawing

Tags: kinect

Good day,

I would like to take this opportunity to give my many thanks to the people of stackoverflow.com.

I have been new to coding, .net, over the past year, and I have always found stakoverflow to be a fantastic base of knowledge for learning.  I spent the last couple weeks working, in depth, on a speech recognition project I am going to use with the upcoming release of Media Browser 3. Originally, the idea was to build a recognizer and have it control media. However as I moved through the different namespaces for speech recognition, it lead me into the realm of the Microsoft Kinect sensor. The more I use the kinect device, the more I would like to use some of the skeleton tracking it has to offer. Which leads me to my question.

I am not interested in build a WPF application that displays a window of what the kinect is seeing. This is part of a Form application, in which I would like to support only two of three gestures.

The idea is for it to watch for three gestures and simulate a key press on the keyboard.
So first I enable skeletonframe before the the audio for the recognizer, because I had read on here somewhere that enabling the skeleton after the audio canceled the audio for some reason.

Then I add some event handlers to my form.

I added skeletonFrameReady event.
I suppose my main questions would be, am I on the right track with skeleton tracking? Is it possible to do this from a form application without trying to draw th skeleton?

Thank you again,
I hope I made sense, sorry for my ignorance.

Ben

Answer (score 0):

It is possible of course. For gesture recognition you can make a comparison between the positions of the joints (In the method that `skeletonFrameReady` event calls, which is called several times per second).

If you want to recognize complex gestures (like waving a hand), I suggest you take a look at this page http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsuksoldev/archive/2011/08/08/writing-a-gesture-service-with-the-kinect-for-windows-sdk.aspx and download the sample code there. (which is hidden in the last paragraph :)

Main idea is checking for predefined gesture segments with the correct order (If the segment1 is successful, look at segment2. If segment2 is paused, look at segment2 again until it is either successful or failed).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh yeah, that was a huge help. Thank you. I still have to work with the segment implementation, but I now understand basic skeleton tracking, and have a swipe left and right that can be added to Media Browser! Very useful, however it took me a second to re work it to the new Kinect SDK 1.7, they no longer use "Research.NUI", and "JointID" is changed to "JointType"

Comment: Since that was an old example you have to rework it to the active SDK you are using. I ported the code to 1.6 SDK and it works very well.